# How does one take Riemann sums without knowing a functions graph

Tags: integration

For example:
Finding the upper, lower, left, right and midpoint sum of $$ \displaystyle\int_{-1}^{3}  (x^{2}-x-1)dx $$
$$ P = { -1, 0, \frac{3}{2} , 3 } $$

First, I don't know what the graph of this function would look like so I've been driven to alternative ways of solving Riemann sums.

The way I would find the upper, lower, left, right and midpoint sum would be to break the partition in sub-intervals. $$ (-1,0),(0,\frac{3}{2}),(\frac{3}{2},3) $$

Then, I would take each number in the sub-interval and plug that into the original function to see which is the greater value and which is the lower value.

For the first sub interval $$(-1,0)$$:
$$(-1)^{2}-(-1)-1) = 1 $$ so this tells me that 1 is my upper in that sub-interval
$$ (0)^{2}-(0)-1) = -1 $$ and this tells me that -1 is my lower in that sub-interval

Then the next sub-interval $$(0,\frac{3}{2})$$:
$$ (0)^{2}-(0)-1) = -1 $$ so -1 this is the upper
$$ (\frac{3}{2})^{2}-1) = \frac{-1}{4} $$ and $$\frac{-1}{4}$$ is the lower

Then the next sub-interval:$$(\frac{3}{2},3)$$
$$ (\frac{3}{2})^{2}-1) = \frac{-1}{4} $$ so $$\frac{-1}{4}$$ is my lower
$$ (3)^{2}-(3)-1) = 5 $$ and 5 is my upper

So find the distance of each sub interval I get $$ -1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2} $$

Altogether now
for the lower sum: $$ (-1)(-1)+(\frac{-1}{4})(\frac{3}{2})+(\frac{-1}{4})(\frac{3}{2}) $$

for the upper sum: $$ (1)(-1)+(-1)(\frac{3}{2})+(5)(\frac{3}{2}) $$

For the midpoint, left and right sum I would have no idea how to solve.

Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you